# Array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

everyone, I'm stuck. The function isGrid returns true if twoD is an array of arrays in that each row has the same number of columns, it returns false otherwise. I'm think I'm supposed to compare the length of two of the functions but I'm stuck

```
    function isGrid(twoD) {
        var isMatrix = true;
        while(twoD.length!==isGrid)
             isMatrix= false; 
    }  
        return isMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: This is has no sense `twoD.length!==isGrid`!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Array#every` to determine if every nested array of given array has the same length by comparing it to e.g. the first nested array.

```js
var arr1 = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
    arr2 = [[1,2], [1,2,3]];
    
    function check(arr){
      return arr.every(v => v.length == arr[0].length);
    }
    
    console.log(check(arr1));
    console.log(check(arr2));
```

Comment: `Array.isArray(arr) && arr.every(v => Array.isArray(v) && v.length == arr[0].length)` Checking that the objects are arrays may be worthwhile as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. I refactored your code a little bit. Pure javascript, no ES6 helpers.

```js
var example1 = [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2]],
  example2 = [[2,2], [1,1]],
    example3 = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]];
  
function isGrid(twoD) {
  var isMatrix = true;
  var arrayToCompare = twoD[0];

  // We start from second element in Array
  for (i = 1; i < twoD.length; i++) {
    var compareWith = twoD[i];

    for (j = 0; j < arrayToCompare.length; j++) {
      var arrayToCompareElements = arrayToCompare[j];

      //console.log(arrayToCompareElements, compareWith[j]);

      if (arrayToCompareElements !== compareWith[j]) {
        isMatrix = false;
        break;
      }
    }


    arrayToCompare = compareWith;
  }

  return isMatrix;
}

console.log(isGrid(example1));
console.log(isGrid(example2));
console.log(isGrid(example3));
```